# node js returning mysql data to variables

Tags: node.js, express, pug, node-mysql

I'm trying to use node js and mysql, along with rendering data from my database into a view.

The issue is, how do I render multiple pieces of data within 1 view (Using jade template).

```
router.get('/about', function(req, res) {

  var animalsData = sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM animals").success(function(rows) {
     return rows;
  });
  console.log(animals); // returns 'undefined'

  var humansData = sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM humans").success(function(rows) {
    return rows;
  });
  console.log(humans); // returns 'undefined'

  res.render('about', { animals: animalsData, humans: humansData });
});
```

As you can see, how can I get the data and then pass it into the view? Using nested callbacks can get messy if theres 5 or 6 bits of data (mysql queries) I wish to pass into the view?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot send data to front end without that data fetched. That being said, your code only looks ugly but apart from that I don't see any problem with nesting since it is a get operation. It would have been another story if it was write. I can only suggest [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) for this.

Answer (score 0):

First of, those returns don't work. The code that you are running is asynch. I would suggest you to use promises:

```
var q = require("q");

router.get('/about', function(req, res) {
  var animalDeferer = q.defer(),
      humanDeferer = q.defer;

  sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM animals").success(function(rows) {
     animalDeferer.resolve(rows);
  });

  sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM humans").success(function(rows) {
     humanDeferer.resolve(rows);
  });

  Q.all([animalDeferer.promsie, humanDeferer.promise]).spread( function(animalsData, humansData) {
    res.render('about', { animals: animalsData, humans: humansData });
  });

});
```

I wrote this directly on the answerbox so it may have typos.

q - https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Comment: Hi thanks very much for the help. Makes sense. I get the following error though "Q is not defined". Do I need to define this somewhere? Or perhaps Im missing something?

Comment: you need to add it to your dependencies and install it

Comment: its there.. I added var q = require("q"); to the top of the file and installed it successfully.. is there another package called Q (big Q) ?

Comment: nop, it's the one I linked in the end of the answer